# ldap authentication varieties in PHP

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

In PHP (any version with ldap_bind) I am wondering why some active directory servers binds with method 1 and some with method 2 as found below, anyone cares to explain to me why? Is it because of the Microsoft server version or some special configuration?

Kindly note that the only difference is the $username value passed as argument to the function, in one it's concatenated with the $server and the other its not.

**Method 1**

```
ldap_bind($ldap_connection, $username . '@' . $server, $password)
```

**Method 2**

```
ldap_bind($ldap_connection, $username, $password)
```

For ease of reference in case anyone needs, [official doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-bind.php) on ldap_bind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are valid, and in most cases both will work. The full list of formats allowed for LDAP binding with AD are listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/6a5891b8-928e-4b75-a4a5-0e3b77eaca52).

If you are authenticating with an account that is on the same domain as the server you are connecting to, then you do not need to provide the domain name with the username (the `sAMAccountName` attribute).

If you are authenticating with an account that is on a different domain than the server, then you do need to provide the domain name with the username in any format that you can do so. For example (if the domain is example.com):

- EXAMPLE\username
- username@example.com
- CN=theuser,OU=users,DC=example,DC=com
- example.com/Users/theuser

Comment: Thank you Gabriel! Nice answer, very informative! I am reading the MS docs and trying to figure out why two of my clients where I implemented this with similar setups work differently and only either/or of those methods work. And in both cases I am connecting from same domain, there must be a catch somewhere! Surely gonna learn something new today :)